# Anbox on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, anbox

I have installed anbox on Ubuntu (using snap).

On Anbox Install Kernal Module page it is mentioned that " Starting with Ubuntu 19.04 binder and ashmem are now build with the standard Ubuntu kernel (>= 5.0) and you don’t have to install the modules from the PPA anymore ". Now when I run anbox only the starting screen appears and then it disappears and nothing opens.
I am unable to figure out how to proceed further.

On using " sudo modprobe ashmem_linux " command i get -
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ashmem_linux': Operation not permitted

$ ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
ls: cannot access '/dev/ashmem': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @DavidPowell after turning off the secure boot the app is working but with secure boot on i was unable to find the solution

Comment: @DavidPowell here is a link that might be helpful in disabling secure boot https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Answer (score 0):

I think running Anbox with `EGL_PLATFORM` variable set to `x11` helped me.
You can either run `EGL_PLATFORM=x11 anbox` or

```bsh
export EGL_PLATFORM=x11
anbox
```

I think it's not important if You use X11 or Wayland.

To be able to start an application with Anbox in a typical way (not from the console) You may need to edit a specific '.desktop' file.

There's also a similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1865) (and I think is possible that I've found this solution there).